# Use a catkin package that depends on a rosbuild package

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to use a rosbuild package as dependency of my catkin package. But I'm getting some some errors... seems that catkin doesn't recognize the rosbuild package. Is there a way I can include that rosbuild package without converting it to a catkin package?

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152326/use-a-catkin-package-that-depends-on-a-rosbuild-package/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2014-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is not possible. You can only depend on catkin packages in rosbuild ones, not the other way around. See also note [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Prerequisites). There might be some very hacky ways doing it by using cmake, custom scripts and fixed paths or so, but the recommended way is converting all dependencies to catkin.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2014-04-13**:
Well I think it should be the opposite, because catkin is more recent... So strange
So, if I create my catkin package as a rosbuild package, I will be able to include all the catkin packages as dependencies, right? Is it possible in ROS Hydro?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-13**:
Yes, but as of Hydro you can not release a rosbuild package anymore.